# Xamarin.Forms How can I disable hover highlight effect on listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms project that uses a Listview.

In this listview, I use a datatemplate to show my own made cards in the listview. The listview with my custom made cards renders correctly, however there is one thing that doesn't go as expected.

In the UWP application, when I hover over an item in the listview, a hover highlight colour appears on my card. I want to **disable the hover effect** completely **for all listviews** in the app.

I know this is standard behaviour in a UWP application but I like to disabled it completely.

I already tried to make a control template in App.xaml, but I can't get it working. I already tought to make a custom renderer but I don't know how I can do this.

I also use a custom control (FlowListView by DLToolkit) which also uses a hover effect just like listview.

**How can I disable the hover highlight colour effect in a listview/FlowListView using Xamarin.Forms?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by setting `FlowTappedBackgroundColor` and `FlowRowBackgroundColor` to a same colour.

**Note** that the highlight colour is still there, however you can't notice because the highlight colour is the same as the background colour.

```
lstFlowList.FlowTappedBackgroundColor = Color.White;
lstFlowList.FlowRowBackgroundColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: These properties don't seem to exist on ListView

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works. But have you tried disabling itemSelection:

```
MyListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
     ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

 ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;  disables the focus colour when you clicked on an item.

I try to disable the hover colour in UWP.
I already managed to disable the colour highlight on an item where you clicked on.